# Inserting Data According To Dropdownlist Criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got  2 datetimepicker, 1 dropdownlist, 1 gridview, 4 textboxes and 1 button in my asp.net project.

I choose the dates from datetimepicker and i choose the employee name from dropdownlist.

After i get the gridview according to that criterias. After that, i want to enter values in to the textboxes and i want to insert that values into the database with my button1_click event. Or if i can do that on source side.

How can i do that ? Please help.
Here is .cs codes ;

```
SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string strSQL = "Insert INTO penalties(DAY,P1,P2,OVER) Values (@DAY,@P1,@P2,@OVER)";
        string bag_str = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["asgdb01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(bag_str);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DAY", TextBox3.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@P1", TextBox4.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@P2", TextBox5.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OVER", TextBox6.Text));

        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        if (i > 0)
            Response.Write("Data Inserted");
        else
            Response.Write("Error");
```

I need the where condition after inserting values but how will i put that condition ? I got control parameter in source side like this ;

```
<InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Textbox1" Name="date1" Type="DateTime" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Textbox2" Name="date2" Type="DateTime" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="name1" Type="String" PropertyName="Text" />
    </InsertParameters>
```

Waiting your answers.

Comment: What have you actually tried on your own..? can you provide or show some code that you have at least attempted on your own..? also what type of database are you using..? this is not that difficult but showing some initial initiative would be nice further more what data will be presented in the GridView..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question more complicated and answered myself on this topic here ; [Update Database with Conditions By Using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123899/update-database-with-conditions-by-using-c-sharp)